# MonoTouch UITableView Questions

Tags: .net, ios, xamarin.ios, uitableview

I am using a `UITableView` in my application.  I have the following questions:

1. I need to know when a user selected a row.  From what I gather, I need to write a class that implements the `UITableViewDelegate`.  Then I need to override the `RowSelected` method.  Is there anyway to do this in my controller (as opposed to creating another class).  It seems like overkill.  Something like `myTableView.RowSelected += MyMethod()`.  I'm not sure why `RowSelected` is not an event in the first place...
2. I want to clip the title of a `UITableView` (text in the header) on the left hand side (default is the right).  I know you can set the `LineBreakMode`, but it seems like I have to do this in the `GetViewForHeader` method (creating my own `UIView` that is in the header).  Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoTouch offers (close to) full bindings to the iOS SDK - i.e. some stuff already exists in the .NET base class library and are not duplicated (but we'll add them if you need them, just fill a [bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) report in such cases).

In general those bindings are **very** close to the original API (either **C** or Objective-C based) since:

- the binding process is largely automated using the **btouch** tool supplied with MonoTouch (which you can use to bind your own ObjectiveC API);
- it really helps porting existsing code, finding code samples and API documentation (Apple developer site, blogs, questions here on stackoverflow.com...)

> I'm not sure why RowSelected is not an event in the first place...

Events, like .NET provides, do not exists in Objective-C. In **many** (but not all) cases MonoTouch added .NET-style events that allows you to avoid defining your own `xxxDelegates` types. In general the events are named `On` + the name of the delegate selector.

> Is there a simpler way to do this?

In case of `UITableView` the (ObjectiveC) API is *IMHO* a bit confusing - but there's an alternative: [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog). It makes working with tables **much** easier and has a .NET-friendly API.

p.s. please try to ask only one question per entry since you can't mark multiple anwers as **accepted**. It also help people who looks for similar questions/answers on the site.